# Count specifict values withing a column by title

Tags: jquery

im having difficulty getting the right count of rows where the call value is "Yes" but on for column 7 or title "1stCountassignedto" e.g the column "count start" would return a value of 3 yeses or 2 nos and column "count end " would return 3 nos or 2 yeses, thanks in advance for all your help have a pleasant day

MY CODE

```
<tr><th>count start</th><th>count end</th></tr>

<tr><td>yes</td><td>no</td></tr>
<tr><td>no</td><td>yes</td></tr>
<tr><td>no</td><td>yes</td></tr>
<tr><td>yes</td><td>no</td></tr>
<tr><td>yes</td><td>no</td></tr>
```

Comment: You need to research the jQuery `.each()` function.

Comment: And/or `.filter( function( index ) )`

Comment: I'm guessing you want this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/L45Gj/1/**

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var yesCount = 0;
var noCount = 0;

//loop through each row cell (I would add class to all rows or id to a table
$('tr td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'yes') {
       yesCount++;
    } else if ($(this).text() == 'no') {
       noCount++;
    }
});
```

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information i provide,this for a SharePoint 2010 project for a list view which would add the same class to td:s the class is class="ms-vb2" this is what i have so far var n1 = jQuery('[name="_x0031_stCountAssignTo"] tr:contains("Yes")').length; it always returns 1 or 0 this is my first time posting a question so i may need some feedback on what information is needed so that you may guide me in the right direction. thanks